# What are the Lévy processes with specific increments?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, levy-processes

It is known that the increment of the Wiener process $W$ is drawn from a Gaussian distribution, i.e. $\Delta W \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \delta t)$.

I wonder what are the Lévy processes with increments from other distributions like the uniform distribution $\Delta \sim \operatorname{Uniform}$, logistic distribution $\Delta \sim \operatorname{Logstic}$, etc. And, do these stochastic processes have corresponding formal names ?

Comment: Every Lévy process $(X_t)$ can be written as $X_t = at + \sigma B_t + P_t$ by the Lévy–Itô decomposition theorem, e.g., see https://books.google.com/books?id=gbe8L1i6trYC&pg=PA112 . Here $B_t$ is a standard Brownian motion, $P_t$ is a compound Poisson process, and $B_t$ & $P_t$ are independent processes. In particular, increments of a Lévy process are independent sums of  a Gaussian r.v. and a compound Poisson r.v., plus a drift.

Comment: I think this remarkable result has to do with the fact that the distributions we are allowed to draw from must be a convolution semigroup. Not every distribution has this property.

Comment: @Onur Oktay: The process $P$ in the Lévy-Ito decomposition is a *limit* of compound Poisson processes, but the jumps of $P$ might be dense in time; viz. a stable Lévy process.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Thank you for filling in what was missing. Indeed for a given $\eta>0$, $P_t = P^1_t + P^2_t$ where $P^1_t$ is a compound Poisson process with jump sizes $\geq\eta$, and $P^2_t$ is a compensated Poisson process with jump sizes $<\eta$. As $\eta\to 0$, $P^1_t\to P_t$ in probability. I should have kept in mind that "everything should be made as simple as possible, but not simpler".